# How to protect firebase credentials in my react app?

Tags: firebase, security

I've created an app using React for the frontend, and firebase for the backend. I've put the firebase credentials in an env file, and access the values from there, but it seems that the firebase credentials are still visible to the end users if they check the source. How should I store these credentials so that this data is not visible to the end users?

Comment: I'm interessted, too. Same with my Angular project 

Comment: The Firebase config values you're working with are not "credentials".  They are just configuration, and they must absolutely exist within your app in order for it to work correctly. You can store them on your backend, but then you would still need to get them to your frontend to initialize Firebase, which means they are not really hidden at all.